# MVC Post form data to async task in home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am new to threading and I have an async Task I need to post view data to this task.

This is where I am at and I am running out of time:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Pay(string amount, string cardExpirtyDate, string cardHolderName, string cardNumber)

    public async Task<ActionResult> PayAsync(FormCollection form)
    {
        var amount = form["amount"].ToString();
        var cardExpirtyDate = form["cardExpirtyDate"].ToString();
        var cardHolderName = form["cardHolderName"].ToString();
        var cardNumber = "4111111111111111";
        var customerId = 23;//Internal purpose to track which customer made the transaction....
        var paymentService = new PaymentService(amount, cardExpirtyDate, cardHolderName, cardNumber, customerId.ToString());
        var transactionResult = await paymentService.PostAsync();
        if (transactionResult == null) return View();

        if (transactionResult.TransactionApproved && !transactionResult.TransactionError
                && transactionResult.CustomerRef == customerId.ToString())
        {
            //transaction success....Go to payment Response and send the variables

            TempData["TRANSACTION_STATUS"] = "APPROVED";
        }
        else
        {
            var message = transactionResult.Message;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And it expects a ;. I tried adding  {} around the async task and that didnt work either.

The View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        Amount:    <input type="text" name="amount" /><br />
        Expirty:   <input type="text" name="cardExpirtyDate" /><br />
        Name:   <input type="text" name="cardHolderName" /><br />
        Number:   <input type="text" name="cardNumber" /><br />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />


    }
@if (TempData["TRANSACTION_STATUS"] != null && TempData["TRANSACTION_STATUS"] == "APPROVED")
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">Your transaction has been processed successfully. Thank you.</div>
}
else
{

    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">There is an issue with this transaction. Please try a different card.</div>
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look,
Doug

Comment: What's your question?  In what way is this code not working?

Comment: It will not compile. it expects a semi colon ;

Comment: It looks like you are making a method inside of another method.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish there?

Comment: Post data from the view to pay. Can I post directly to PayAsync from the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are trying to accomplish. Just make your main request async instead of having it to try and call another.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult>  Pay(FormCollection form)
    var amount = form["amount"].ToString();
    var cardExpirtyDate = form["cardExpirtyDate"].ToString();
    var cardHolderName = form["cardHolderName"].ToString();
    var cardNumber = "4111111111111111";
    var customerId = 23;//Internal purpose to track which customer made the transaction....
    var paymentService = new PaymentService(amount, cardExpirtyDate, cardHolderName, cardNumber, customerId.ToString());
    var transactionResult = await paymentService.PostAsync();
    if (transactionResult == null) return View();

    if (transactionResult.TransactionApproved && !transactionResult.TransactionError
            && transactionResult.CustomerRef == customerId.ToString())
    {
        //transaction success....Go to payment Response and send the variables

        TempData["TRANSACTION_STATUS"] = "APPROVED";
    }
    else
    {
        var message = transactionResult.Message;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you acastr7. I posted directly to PayAsync using @using (Html.BeginForm("PayAsync", "Home")) and it worked but this works better because I can use the same view. Sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method header with no method body:

```
public ActionResult Pay(string amount, string cardExpirtyDate, string cardHolderName, string cardNumber)
```

Either define a body for the method, or remove the header.

The compiler error (or errors) might not be obvious in this case, since what you have is a pretty glaring structural error in your class.  The compiler just can't make sense of it at all in this case.

Comment: i tried to add brackets {} around PayAsync making that the body but that did not work either.

Comment: @DougFarrell: The `PayAsync` method already *has* curly braces around its method body.  At quick glance, that method seems fine.  The problem is your other method, `Pay`.  You didn't define it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to create a method inside a method.

```
public ActionResult Pay(string amount, string cardExpirtyDate, string cardHolderName, string cardNumber) {
     public async Task<ActionResult> PayAsync(FormCollection form) {
            //... Your code ...
     }
}
```

What are you trying to accomplish here?

You should have only one method :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> PayAsync(FormCollection form) {
   // ... Your code...
}
```

Comment: Can I post directly to PayAsync from the Pay view?